# Conservation of String in Double Atwood Machines

Tags: classical-mechanics

Consider the double Atwood machine in the image

[image]

Using conservation of string, how would one prove mathematically that $a_1$ = $-\frac{a_2 + a_3}{2}$?

There is a video trying to prove this by taking the derivative of the string's length two times to get the acceleration relationship.
It is as follows:

[image]

$l_2 = x_2 - l$

$l_3 = x_3 - l$

$l_2 + l_3 = C$    because the string is conserved

$(x_2 - l) + (x_3 - l) = C$

taking the derivative two times we get:

$(a_2 - a_p) + (a_3 - a_p) = 0$

where $a_p$ is the acceleration of the bottom pulley
and because $a_p$ = $-a_1$

$a_2 + a_3 + 2 a_1 = 0$

$a_1$ = $-\frac{a_2 + a_3}{2}$

But isn't this wrong? Doesn't taking the derivative of $(x_2 - l) + (x_3 - l) = C$
two times result in $((a_2 + a_p) - a_p) + ((a_3 + a_p) - a_p) = 0$ since $x_2$ and $x_3$ both depends on $l$ and $l_2$ & $l_3$ respectively?
This just gives the not so interesting result $a_2 = -a_3$.

Am I missing something here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: But l is not the total length of the top string (only the right side) and can move up (decrease) or down (increase). Even if we assume $dl/dt$ to be 0, $a_p$ will be zero, hence still reducing the equation to $a_p = −a_1$. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are right. I jumped the gun. Why do you think that $\frac{d^2 x_2}{dt^2} = a_2+a_p$? instead of just $a_2$? $x_2$ is the distance of the second block from a fixed origin point so its second derivative will be its own acceleration.

Comment: @Prahar My original thought of why it should be $a_2 + a_p$ is because $x_2$ increases as $m_2$ and the pulley rope accelerate downwards. But now that I think about it, my idea was flawed since it was assuming $a_2$ to be the acceleration relative to its (immediate) pulley. So it should be as you said, the second derivative should be its own acceleration. Did I correctly point out my mistake?

Comment: yes, you did indeed.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "string is conserved"? Energy and momentum is conserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

How to obtain the kinematic equations.

I use the Instant center of rotation ICO to obtain the velocities equations.

$$\omega\,L=v_2\\
\omega\,(L+R)=v_1\\
\omega\,(L+2\,R)=v_3$$

thus
$$v_2=\frac{L}{L+R}\,v_1\\
v_3=\frac{L+2\,R}{L+R}\,v_1\quad\Rightarrow\\
v_1=\frac{v_2+v_3}{2}$$

Comment: Splendid! Thank you for your answer!